# Ecryptfs directory on USB Drive

Tags: ubuntu, ecryptfs

I have an encrypted directory on my USB drive that I encrypted using ecryptfs on an old computer.  I know the passphrase I used at the time to encrypt this directory but I cant seem to decrypt it on a new machine with the same passphrase.

Is is possible to do this on a new machine? Or the old machine contains some key unique to the passphrase that cannot be recreated on my new machine?

Thanks for any input.

Tony

Comment: I figured it out, it does work fine on the new machine when you enter the correct passphrase

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.